# I am trying to perform click operation on performing file upload but not able to perform

Tags: java, xpath, file-upload, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to perform click operation on performing file upload
The code of html for the page is

```
<button class="w85bt fl" onclick="clearDefaultTextCV('copyPaste');truncateTextCv();if(gbi('upUrl').value != 'false' || gbi('copyPaste').value.length>0){gbi('editForm').submit();}" type="button">
<div>
<p><p/>
<b>Save</b>
<em/>
```

```
WebElement savebutton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".w85bt.fl"));
System.out.println(savebutton);
savebutton .click();
```

I am performing the ablove mentioned operation.
But my code fails to perform click operation.
It does not throw exception no such element found

Comment: Does it print the `savebutton` or fails before?

Comment: hi provide more HTML code to try with another locator. also did you tried same by providing sleep may Thread.sleep(3000) before click. some time sleep before click will simulate correctly.

Comment: It prints the save button but it fails to perform the click operation

Answer (score 0):

I am considering that your locator is fine and able to locate the element

Now use below code for click on button

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".w85bt.fl"));

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

If still not working then check if there is any frame present in your DOM.
If there is no frame then check your locator, May be your locator have an issue

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Your_FileUpload_id")).sendKeys("C:\\Your_FilePath");
Thread.sleep(2000);

driver.findElement(By.id(uiMaps.getProperty("UploadOption"))).click();
```

Hope it worked for you.

Comment: Can you please let me know what does uiMaps because it shows error uiMaps cannot be resolved thanks for the help

Comment: UIMap is a concept for defining, storing, and serving UI elements of an application or a website. The UIMap properties file contains a set of ‘key-value’ pairs, where key is an alias of the UI element, and a value is the locator.     For simplicity you can use the following code:   driver.findElement(By.id("Your_UploadButton_id")).click();